# NAS requirements for incremental backups on windows SBS 2011

Tags: windows-backup, windows-sbs

I would like to do incremental backups using windows-backup on a NAS with sbs 2011, I googled and found that iSCSI is required, is this the only thing the nas must support to be able to do incremental backups?

I was thinking about Synology Diskstation, which should support iSCSI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iSCSI should be the only requirement you need to meet.  To give you a little more infor on iSCSI vs normal folder backup:

There are actually 2 ways in which SBS Backup can access a NAS.

One logical approach is to use a windows network share for the destination, however because the destination is not accessible at the disk sector level, the incremental imaging feature can’t be used. A full image backup must be taken each time the job runs which can take significantly more time as well as requiring a larger amount of storage if you wish to keep multiple images.

The second is iSCSI as you mentioned.

The difference between teh two is that an iSCSI device is "block level" storage as opposed to file level storage.  This means that multiple servers can have it "mounted" exclusively at once without an effect on performance or availability.

If you were to use windows file shares for backup, a new image would need to be taken when backing up large files such as VHDs or larger databases, whereas iSCSI can backup the differential blocks and create incrementals - much more efficient and just as rhobust.